# which rails 2 authentication plugin for Twitter and/or Facebook and/or "normal" accounts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, oauth, account, user-accounts

Using the current rails 2

I want users to be able to create an account from:

- traditional signup
- twitter
- facebook

and then allow them to link facebook and/or twitter and/or traditional signup later.

I read this http://www.themomorohoax.com/2009/02/21/rails-2-3-authentication-comparison
 and decided to check out:

- Authlogic
- Restful Authentication
- Devise/Warden

It seems for at least some of the plugins you can use with them that making OAuth work with them will make them incompatible with any other login system.

Will I need to roll my own from the ground up, or can I glue together some existing pieces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can glue together existing pieces.
I wouldn't advise for Restful Authentication. It's getting old and isn't maintained anymore.

If you plan on using Authlogic, you can take a look at those two gems :

- [authlogic oauth](http://github.com/jrallison/authlogic_oauth) for any oauth service (including twitter)
- [authlogic facebook connect](http://github.com/kalasjocke/authlogic_facebook_connect)

If you plan on using Devise, you can take a look at those two gems :

- [warden oauth](http://github.com/roman/warden_oauth) for any oauth service (including twitter)
- [device facebook connectable](http://github.com/grimen/devise_facebook_connectable)

Comment: Thanks for the links. I am concerned about these scenarios:

For different accounts:
Will those Authlogic plugins play nice side by side, with each other and with "normal" authentication?

For combining on the one account:
They seem to allow the creation of other accounts, with no provision for linking oauth login to an existing account, or similar

Do the plugins assume they are they only way the account can be logged into, or will they play nice with others?

Comment: I haven't tried authlogic. But the devise ones plays quite nice with each other. I was able to provide the ability for one use to log himself in from facebook, twitter and password to the same account without notable problems.